# Spring: Get File Input Stream from Form Data

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have a page that uses form for file uploading. I meet an issue that the backend is not able to receive the file input stream.
This is the source data:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryF5NgIFolyKIoQrg9
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="Screenshot 2019-10-31 at 12.13.53.png"
Content-Type: image/png


------WebKitFormBoundaryF5NgIFolyKIoQrg9
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"

Screenshot 2019-10-31 at 12.13.53.png
------WebKitFormBoundaryF5NgIFolyKIoQrg9
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="mimeType"

image/png
------WebKitFormBoundaryF5NgIFolyKIoQrg9--
```

In the backend, I am using the code below to get fileName and fileStream:

```
 public ResponseEntity uploadProxy(@Context HttpServletRequest req,
            @FormDataParam("file") InputStream fileStream,
            @FormDataParam("name") String fileName)
```

However, these values are all null.

I tried this, it works. But, I can get only the file name rather than the input stream.

```
((StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest) req).getRequest().getParameter("name")
```

I checked other post, but I didn't find a solution using `FormDataParam`. Can I get some about the error in my code?

Thanks!

Comment: is there any particular need to have InputStream? The `MultipartFile` class is commonly used to handle file upload in Spring controllers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the multipartfile encryption on with a web html form.
And then, in your class in charge of the operation, get the inputStrem by a requesteMapping (get or post) and a requestParameter like this:

```
    <HTML> 
    <form action="fileupload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <div class="form-groups">
        <label for="fileupload"> Locate file </label>
        <input type="file" class="form-control" id="file" name="file" />
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> submit </button>
    </form>
    </HTML>
```

```
     @PostMapping( value="/fileupload" )
         public String your_method_name_eg_uploadProxy( @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws IOException{
         //try
         File convertFile = new File ("directory_path");
         convertFile.createNewFile();
         FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(convertFile); 
         fos.write(file.getBytes());
         fos.close(); 
         return "succes";
     }
```

This allows you to stream the info of your files by Bytes into a newFile.
Also, remember to import the java.io.util libs as needed if it is the case.

Hope it helps anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

**Please use below code retrieve value**

***Best answer for your scenarios and refer below for more ways to achieve***

```
((Servlet30RequestWrapper) request).getRequest().getParameter("name")
```

**Ways to convert an InputStream to a String:**

***Using IOUtils.toString (Apache Utils)***

```
String result = IOUtils.toString(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

***Using CharStreams (Guava)***

```
 String result = CharStreams.toString(new InputStreamReader(
       inputStream, Charsets.UTF_8));
```

***Using Scanner (JDK)***

```
 Scanner s = new Scanner(inputStream).useDelimiter("\\A");
 String result = s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "";
```

***Using InputStreamReader and StringBuilder (JDK)***

```
 int bufferSize = 1024;
 char[] buffer = new char[bufferSize];
 StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
 Reader in = new InputStreamReader(stream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
 for (int numRead; (numRead = in.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) > 0; ) {
     out.append(buffer, 0, numRead);
 }
 return out.toString();
```

***Using StringWriter and IOUtils.copy (Apache Commons)***

```
 StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
 IOUtils.copy(inputStream, writer, "UTF-8");
 return writer.toString();
```

***Using ByteArrayOutputStream and inputStream.read (JDK)***

```
 ByteArrayOutputStream result = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
 byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
 for (int length; (length = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1; ) {
     result.write(buffer, 0, length);
 }

 // StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name() > JDK 7
 return result.toString("UTF-8");
```

***Using BufferedInputStream and ByteArrayOutputStream (JDK)***

```
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);
ByteArrayOutputStream buf = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
for (int result = bis.read(); result != -1; result = bis.read()) {
    buf.write((byte) result);
}
// StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name() > JDK 7
return buf.toString("UTF-8");
```